# Android Studio: Teclado numerico no incluye el punto en dispositivo tablet

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una aplicación con un un campo en el que quiero que únicamente me acepte dígitos y el punto "`.`".

En un teléfono móvil me muestra correctamente el teclado de la aplicación con los dígitos y el punto, pero en una tablet solo aparece el teclado numerico, sin el punto.

Este es mi código en el layout:

```
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/marcoIpRed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Error">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/cmpIpRed"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="ip de red"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:digits="0123456789."
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como no se las versiones del smartphone y tablet que estas utilizando, prueba con un simple edittext de esta forma:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/cmpIpRed" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="ip de red" android:inputType="number|numberDecimal|numberSigned" android:singleLine="true" android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

en el inputText del Editext colocas estos datos:

- "number"

para hacer referencia a "numeros" solo

- "numberDecimal"

referencia a numeros decimales

- "numberSigned"

referencia a numeros con signos positivo y negativo

En el inputText , en lugar de colocar los tres datos puedes colocar solo dos , o solo uno

Aunque si quieres tambien se puede crear con codigo java o kotlin mediante  constantes de la Clase InputText , como por ejemplo TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL o TYPE_NUMBER

yo siempre lo hago asi y me funciona

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero usar :

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

esto habilitara nùmeros y decimales incluyendo el punto.

> el número es decimal, lo que permite que un punto decimal proporcione
>   valores fraccionarios.

Programaticamente lo puedes definir tambièn de esta forma:

```
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Con ambas opciones puedes tener el mismo resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]